# Concatenate other command output with echo in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my current code:

```
for j in {1..10}
do
  echo $j ./gcc-$j.out >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

I want to execute each .out file with its prefix and output them into the txt file.

Each .out file output only have one line, my input is:

```
gcc-1.out
gcc-2.out
gcc-3.out
gcc-4.out
gcc-7.out
gcc-8.out
```

my expected output in `gcc-result.txt` is:

```
1someoutput
2someoutput
3someoutput
4someoutput
7someoutput
8someoutput
```

My current code is not working for my requirement, my current output is:

```
1 ./gcc-1.out
2 ./gcc-2.out
3 ./gcc-3.out
4 ./gcc-4.out
7 ./gcc-7.out
8 ./gcc-8.out
```

It just included my filename rather than the execution result.

any suggestion for fixing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output just include my file name of my .out file rather than its execution result. Something like: 1 ./gcc-1.out 2 ./gcc-2.out 3 ./gcc-3.out...

Comment: Put it in the question so others can see and format it please :)

Comment: Thank you, I've put it into the question.

Comment: So you want  to echo a number then the contents from the file ?Also is that `1` before the `echo` a typo ?

Comment: Exactly., that is what I am looking for. Yes that was a typo, I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

```
for j in {1..10} do
    echo -n $j >> gcc-result.txt
    ./gcc-$j.out >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

the -n prevents echo from doing a new line.   You could also do:

```
for j in {1..10} do
    echo $j `./gcc-$j.out` >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

The backqoutes mean run the enclosed text as a command and use the output as a string.

Comment: better than backquotes is  $( ... )   in this case $(./gcc-$j.out) ...  and why?    $( ... ) nests, backqoutes will need escapes.  and once you learn the value of this idiom you will soon discover nesting is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (if I correctly understand what you need...):

```
for i in {1..10}
do
  echo -n ${i}`gcc-$i.out` >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

Comment: Yes, end then echo would print it's output. Isn't it the OP requested behavior?

Comment: Yeah, looks that way, i deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in {1..10}
do
  { echo -n "$j"; cat "gcc-${j}.out"; } >> gcc-result.txt
done
```

This assumes you want to concatenate the contents of variable `j` with the contents of file `gcc-$j.out`.

If you write to the same stream in sequence, what you write gets concatenated automatically (naturally).

So you could either:

```
 echo -n "$j" >> gcc-result.txt
 cat "gcc-${j}.out" >> gcc-result.txt
```

Or DRY it up (DRY = don't repeat yourself) by grouping the commands with either parentheses (`()`) (forks a subshell) or curly braces (`{}`) (executes in the same shell) and redirect output for the whole group as shown in the proposed solution.

Technically, you don't need the quotes and `${j}`, but it's a good habit to get into to increase overall robustness of your code.